# HQL: Path expected for join! could not resolve property

Tags: java, sql, hql

I cannot find any documentations on how to treat this situation. I keep receiving the following errors:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: id_alumno_origen
of: dm.model.tramite.TrasladoInterno
....
antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!
```

I am using the following query, although I found some solution referring the lack of referencing to the fields in the case of `JOIN + ON`, I had no luck:

```
from pe.edu.innovaschools.dm.model.tramite.TrasladoInterno a
    JOIN  gen_sede b ON b.id = a.id_sede_destino  
    JOIN  aca_grado c ON a.id_grado_destino = c.id   
    WHERE a.tipo = 'INTERPERIODO'   
        AND a.estado IN ('ACEP' , 'PEND')   
        AND a.id_periodo_origen = :PERIODOORIG   
        AND a.id_periodo_destino = :PERIODODEST   
GROUP BY a.id_sede_destino , b.nombre , a.id_grado_destino , c.nombre_ps , a.estado
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `HQL` I prefer to use implicit JOIN notation (more times explicit `JOIN` can  result wrong).
If you use `GROUP BY`, you must apply a projection to your `SELECT`, so try this:

```
select a.id_sede_destino, b.nombre,
    a.id_grado_destino , c.nombre_ps , a.estado
from pe.edu.innovaschools.dm.model.tramite.TrasladoInterno a,
gen_sede b, 
aca_grado c   
WHERE b.id = a.id_sede_destino 
    AND a.tipo = 'INTERPERIODO'
    AND a.id_grado_destino = c.id
    AND a.estado IN ('ACEP' , 'PEND')   
    AND a.id_periodo_origen = :PERIODOORIG   
    AND a.id_periodo_destino = :PERIODODEST   
GROUP BY a.id_sede_destino, b.nombre,
    a.id_grado_destino , c.nombre_ps , a.estado
```

Comment: Indeed, I try the code undestanding that HQL should be able to know that  a.id_grado_destino = c.id is the linking condition between tables. But still the same problem. So far I just use a SQL sentence to retrieve the data.